# php variable string concatenation

Tags: php

I have the following php var :

```
$mail_from=$full_name." <".$user_obj->getEmailAddress().">";
```

but only the $full_name is capture in `$mail_from.The $user_obj->getEmailAddress()` is not assigned to `$mail_from`.

I `var_dump` both `$full_name` and `$user_obj->getEmailAddress()` and both got value.

Whats wrong?

here are the var_dump value :

```
$full_name : string(12) "TAN CHEN WEI"
$user_obj->getEmailAddress() : string(26) "level2@hartalega-bb.com.my"
$mail_from : string(41) "TAN CHEN WEI "
```

Comment: You should post the results of your var_dump to help you better.

Comment: Could you provide more contextual source code here?

Comment: Try Escaping Buddy.... Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Escaping**

```
$mail_from=$full_name . "&lt;" . $user_obj->getEmailAddress() . "&gt;";
```

**Demo** --- Run the following Code in : http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
function getEmailAddress(){
    return "user@example.com";
}

$full_name = "My Name";
$mail_from = $full_name ."&lt;". getEmailAddress() . "&gt;" ;
echo $mail_from;
```

**Check Manual** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score -1):

```
 $mail_from="{$full_name}{'<'}{$user_obj->getEmailAddress()}{'>'}";
```

Use double quotes to concat more than two strings instead of multiple '.' operators.  PHP is forced to re-concatenate with every '.' operator.

Answer (score -1):

again check `$user_obj->getEmailAddress()` and try simple way like

```
$mail_from="{$full_name} <{$user_obj->getEmailAddress()}>";
```

Comment: there is problem with your function `$user_obj->getEmailAddress()` check for any other variable , it's working well.